# I need t print html table with window.print() without head repeating in every page

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a html table that has reports on it and when I print that table,table prints head and body rows in every page but I want to print head in just one page and rest of the body should be printed in every next page without head,how  can I achieve it?

I expect table head to print in first page only.

Comment: have you looked at css for printing (`@media print`) - maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32853160/media-print-css-not-formatting-table-on-printing can inspire you?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.